# Update float value in SQLite

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am trying to read `float value`, that I update its value to `SQLite` database. I use `REAL` as a type of float value. The following is the code I use to update `SQLite`:

```
//update download percent
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *update_stmt = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE myTable SET floatValueColumn=%f WHERE id=%i", myProgress, myTargetId] UTF8String];

    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDB, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement)){ //sql fail

            NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(myDB));
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        // Finalize and close database.
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    // close database
    sqlite3_close(myDB);
}
```

There is no error while using above code and I read float value follow the guide of this link [How do you read floating numbers (REAL) from a sqlite database on the iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534931/how-do-you-read-floating-numbers-real-from-a-sqlite-database-on-the-iphone), but I don't know why I don't get my expected value.

`UPDATE`:
I create my database file by using:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                 @"mydbs.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYTABLE (MYFLOATVALUECOLUMN REAL)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(myDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            //alert
        }
        sqlite3_close(myDB);
    } else {
        //alert
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the database file? If it's in the resource bundle you can't write to it. An app's resource bundle is read-only (on a real device).

Comment: OK, you have a database file with no tables. You need to create the tables or supply a pre-made database (with the tables) in your resource bundle and copy that to the Documents directory.

Comment: You're printing `sqlite3_errmsg` if `sqlite3_step` fails, but not if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails. You should do so for both. And you say you don't get the "expected" value. What value are you expecting and what did you get? In regards to your other question, you say you were expecting a "floating point integer", which doesn't makes sense. (is it INTEGER or not?)

Comment: @Rob, I initial my floating column value to 0, and I got 0 when I read it after I update it. it is not integer, it is percent of download file, which is floating point.

Comment: You post all of this code about writing the value but you claim the problem is reading the value. Have you run this code through the debugger? As written above, you silently ignore all possible failures except for the actual database write. Do you know for sure the database is actually being updated? Have you looked at the table after doing this?

Comment: @paim Agreed. Also, you don't seem to do anything if `sqlite3_prepare_v2` fails, so I'm not confident that's not failing. You're also not showing me anything that makes me confident that the row with the `id` equal to `myTargetId` exists (because if not, you wouldn't get any error, but the update would do nothing). It's got to be something simple like that. But you're just not showing us enough.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you very much for your effort, could you please post your answer, so I can vote for you, now I resolve my issue already, by following your suggestion

Comment: @Rob, also help me a lot too, so I won't accept anyone answer but vote for you guys, now I got you guys suggestions and already solve my problem, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @piam What was the problem? I posted several suggestions.

Comment: your suggestion and Rob suggestion mixes together solves my issue, code above is correct, but I misunderstanding about id of row I will update

Comment: @rmaddy , after see Rob's explantion below, I hope you don't mind if I accept his answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You should be checking return codes for *every* `sqlite3_xxx()` call. In your example, you didn't check the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`. So we have no way of knowing whether you even executed the subsequent `sqlite3_step()` call.
2. For diagnostic purposes, if your program isn't behaving like you expect, after your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, especially those with `WHERE` clauses, you should re-retrieve the values and confirm that:

   - it found a row that matched your `WHERE` clause; and
   - the value stored was what you expected.

   In your code sample, you didn't show that you retrieved the value from your database using the same `WHERE` clause, that you actually found a row, and that the value was correct.

I know that this all sounds so simple, but clearly you're not doing one of these steps. And it's impossible for us to tell, without seeing your code, to know what the source of your challenge is. But you shouldn't even bother to share code with us if you're not taking care of points 1 and 2, above.

Below, let me share with you the sort of code that I think you should write. This satisfies both of the criteria above. As you'll see, this code does each of those steps correctly, and everything works fine.

Also notice a more subtle refinement in my code below where, rather than ever building a SQL statement with a `NSString` class method `stringWithFormat`, I *always* use the `?` placeholder for any variable values in my SQL statements, and then use the `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` methods to set those values. You should always "bind" variable values in your SQL statements. Not only is it just good practice, but avoids you needing from worrying about quoting values in `TEXT` columns, protects you against SQL injection attacks, etc.

Anyway, here is some code:

```
//  ViewController.m
//  sqlite demo

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    sqlite3 *database;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self testSqlite];
}

#pragma mark - SQLite methods

// test my database interaction

- (void)testSqlite
{
    if (![self openDb])
        return;

    if (![self dropTable])
    {
        [self closeDb];
        return;
    }

    if (![self createTable])
    {
        [self closeDb];
        return;
    }

    double initialStoredValue = 0.1;
    sqlite3_int64 rowId = [self insertRowWithDouble:initialStoredValue];
    if (rowId < 0)
    {
        [self closeDb];
        return;
    }

    double retrievedValue = [self selectDoubleForRow:rowId];
    NSLog(@"%s inserted row with value of %f, retrieved value of %f", __FUNCTION__, initialStoredValue, retrievedValue);

    double newValue = 0.2;
    if (![self updateRow:rowId withDouble:newValue])
    {
        [self closeDb];
        return;
    }

    retrievedValue = [self selectDoubleForRow:rowId];
    NSLog(@"%s updated row with value of %f, retrieved value of %f", __FUNCTION__, newValue, retrievedValue);

    if (![self closeDb])
        return;
}

// return TRUE if successful, FALSE if not

- (BOOL)openDb
{
    NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vdos.db"];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s database open failed", __FUNCTION__);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// return TRUE if successful, FALSE if not

- (BOOL)dropTable
{
    const char *sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable";
    char *errmsg;

    if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql, NULL, NULL, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s table drop failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, errmsg);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// return TRUE if successful, FALSE if not

- (BOOL)createTable
{
    const char *sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, float_column REAL)";
    char *errmsg;

    if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql, NULL, NULL, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s table create failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, errmsg);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// return the primary key of the inserted table
//   -1 = failure

- (sqlite3_int64)insertRowWithDouble:(double)value
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (float_column) VALUES (?)";

    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s prepare failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return -1;
    }

    if (sqlite3_bind_double(statement, 1, value) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s column bind failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return -1;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s step failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return -1;
    }

    if (sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s finalize failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return -1;
    }

    return sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
}

// return float_column value for row with particular rowId

- (double)selectDoubleForRow:(sqlite3_int64)rowId
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *sql = "SELECT float_column FROM mytable WHERE id = ?";

    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s prepare failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, rowId) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s column bind failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s step failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        return FALSE;
    }

    double value = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);

    if (sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s finalize failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return FALSE;
    }

    return value;
}

// return the primary key of the inserted table
//   -1 = failure

- (BOOL)updateRow:(sqlite3_int64)rowId withDouble:(double)value
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *sql = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET float_column = ? WHERE id = ?";

    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s prepare failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (sqlite3_bind_double(statement, 1, value) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s column bind 1 failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 2, rowId) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s column bind 2 failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s step failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (sqlite3_finalize(statement) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s finalize failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

// return TRUE if successful, FALSE if not

- (BOOL)closeDb
{
    if (sqlite3_close(database) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s database close failed", __FUNCTION__);
        return FALSE;
    }

    database = NULL;

    return TRUE;
}

@end
```

Now, to your other question, [How do you read floating numbers (REAL) from a sqlite database on the iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534931), about the value stored in the database being an `INTEGER` or being a `REAL`, the critical issue is that to store `REAL` values, into SQLite, you should use `sqlite3_bind_double` and to read `REAL` values, you should use `sqlite3_column_double`. And if you're not seeing your database reflect the `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements, you're either not successfully checking the result of the `sqlite3_xxx()` function calls, or you have made a mistake in your `WHERE` clause.

---

As an aside, there is an idiosyncrasy of SQLite that you might want to be aware of. Imagine that you replaced the call to `createTable` with a call to `createTableBad` in which my `float_column` is actually defined as an `INTEGER`:

```
// return TRUE if successful, FALSE if not

- (BOOL)createTableBad
{
    const char *sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, float_column INTEGER)";
    char *errmsg;

    if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql, NULL, NULL, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s table create failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, errmsg);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Amazingly, if you use this `createTableBad` in my `testSqlite` method, and the inserting and updating `double` values still works! This is because SQLite is a "dynamic type system" (see the introduction in the SQLite discussion on [data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).

When you insert a floating point value of `0.1` into a column whose column definition is `INTEGER`, it will actually store the value as a `REAL`, regardless of the table's column definition. When you change that value to `0.2`, that will work too. This is because **how data is stored in a table is a function of how it was inserted, not a function of column definition in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.**

To illustrate this even further, consider the absurd example where I define the column to be of type `HIPPOPOTOMUS`!

```
// return TRUE if successful, FALSE if not

- (BOOL)createTableReallyBad
{
    const char *sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, float_column HIPPOPOTOMUS)";
    char *errmsg;

    if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql, NULL, NULL, &errmsg) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s table create failed: \"%s\"", __FUNCTION__, errmsg);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

The code still works!

I'm not saying that you should ever not accurately represent your column types as `INTEGER` or `REAL`, as appropriate. I'm just saying that it's critical to understand that the data type for data in a SQLite database is a function of the `sqlite3_bind_xxx()` statement when you inserted it, not how the table definition allegedly defined the column.